# Is is safe to use requestAnimationFrame in real projects?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I'm wondering if it's safe to use requestAnimationFrame outside of experimenting yet?
I guess you still need the vendor prefixes (moz, ms etc).
How many of the modern browsers support it? And how big are the differences?
I know FF had trouble with the fps capping at 62.5 - callback time.

Also what is the real difference in using requestAnimationFrame when compared to a setInterval loop?

Comment: what you need it for ? concept is well supported by browser vendors, syntax is almost stable (sans the `cancelAnimationFrame` ), and you can safely emulate it through shim in legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe, as long as you are aware the syntax could change, though I doubt it will. Testing is of course important, but I can't see any reason not to, as the enhanced performance is worth it. You can also omit the prefixed version if a browser doesnt work as expected.